# Controling a Washing Machine AC Motor Using a Relay

Tags: solid-state-relay, induction-motor, zero-crossing

I would like to control the motor of my washing machine using an Arduino.
It's an old washing machine with a mechanical controller and an AC motor connected to a 12.5 uF run/start capacitor. According to the motor specs, it operates at 230V and draws 3A (probably not the peak value, but during operation).

**My thoughts:**

I would like to control it using a relay with the lowest budget possible. Since it's a large inductive load I want to avoid mechanical relays, especially the cheap ones available on Aliexpress due to arcing when the connection breaks. I'm afraid such a relay would quickly start malfunctioning.

I could use something like a contactor but they are not cheap.

The [SSR-40D](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1PC-Solid-State-Relay-SSR-40DA-40A-Single-Phase-DC-control-AC-Voltage-Transformer-input-3/32860330749.html?spm=2114.search0604.3.1.5d2d1414jPwyXD&s=p&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536,searchweb201603_54,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=819359af-cde2-472c-b805-980115ad2f0c-0&algo_pvid=819359af-cde2-472c-b805-980115ad2f0c) relays look good and can also be conveniently connected directly to an arduino GPIO, but they are zero-cross relays which are not suitable for controlling large inductive loads due to large current surges. Random triggered or peak-triggered SSR relays are pretty rare and expensive, so I'd like to avoid them.
My thought was to use the zero-cross SSR, with the highest available current rating, like the SSD-100D (100 A) to control the motor.

I would just like to make sure I don't burn our house down with my DIY shenanigans. Namely, what is the peak current flowing through the high voltage side of the relay I should expect from switching on the aforementioned motor at the zero-crossing point for the given specs?

Comment: I'm thinking this might be an X-Y problem, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this concept. Learned something new. I edited the question.

Comment: How about turning the mechanical input into digital input?